# Exception on automatic flush at the end of a transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, flush, transactional

I'm filling a database with entries that should be replaced if they are already present. To do this, first I check if the entry is already present with a find (which is wrapped in a read only transaction), then if the returned value is null, I persist the newly made entry (wrapped in a transaction), if the returned value is an existing entry, I first remove it (wrapped in a transaction) and then add the new entry. Besides the fact that these are a lot of transactions that could be done inside a single transaction, I'm wondering why I get an exception if an entry is already present. I've checked the flush mode and it's set to AUTO, so it should be flushing at the end of a transaction. This is the stacktrace of the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.NaturalIdXrefDelegate.validateNaturalId(NaturalIdXrefDelegate.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.NaturalIdXrefDelegate.cacheNaturalIdCrossReference(NaturalIdXrefDelegate.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext$1.cacheNaturalIdCrossReferenceFromLoad(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:1817)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.getNaturalIdSnapshot(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkNaturalId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:199)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1213)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:402)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:480)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:392)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy31.save(Unknown Source)
    at controller.FileParserCore.update(FileParserCore.java:39)
    at controller.Core.runCore(Core.java:122)
    at controller.Core.staticRunCore(Core.java:74)
    at controller.Core.main(Core.java:33)
```

I'm using Hibernate and Spring.

This is the bit of code that fails if an entry is already present:

```
Entry entry = getNewEntry();
if (entryDAO.find(entry.getName()) != null) {
    entryDAO.remove(entry.getName());
}
entryDAO.save(entry);
```

This is the corresponding DAO:

```
@Repository
public class EntryDAO extends GenericDAO<Entry> implements IEntryDAO {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EntryDAO.class);

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(Entry entry) {
        makePersistent(entry);
        log.info("Saved: {}", entry);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void remove(String name) {
        Entry entry = find(name);
        if (entry != null) {
            makeTransient(entry);
            log.info("Removed: {}", entry);
        } else {
            log.warn("Could not remove: {}, entry not found", name);
        }
    }

    /**
     * find an entry by its name and return it
     */
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Entry find(String name) {
        return (Entry) createCriteria(Restrictions.eq("name",name)).uniqueResult();
    }
}
```

And this is the Entry domain object:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false, of = { "name" })
public class Entry extends DomainObject implements Serializable {
    @NaturalId
    @NotEmpty
    @Length(max = 16)
    @Index(name = "ix_name")
    private String name;
}
```

This is the output up until the exception:

```
INFO  2013-03-01 10:22:17,899 main - Removed: someEntry
INFO  2013-03-01 10:22:18,117 main - Saved: someEntry
```

When I check the database, the old entry is removed, but the new entry is not saved. Also, the IDs of the old entry and the new entry are different, just the names are the same. From the stacktrace it seems like it has something to do with the naturalID, maybe because the flush didn't finish removing the old entry the name of the new entry is clashing with this? But shouldn't the old entry be long gone already when it enters the save() method?

UPDATE:
I also checked whether putting everything within a single transaction would work, but of course it started crying when I tried removing an entry and immediately afterwards adding an entry with the same NaturalID (their name). So I thought: let's put a getCurrentSession().flush() inbetween. Result: the same Exception as above.

UPDATE:
Here's the DomainObject class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EqualsAndHashCode
public abstract class DomainObject implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long    id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public abstract String toString();
}
```

Comment: could you post the code for Entry as well?

Comment: It seems, that for `DomainObject` there is improperly set `@Id` or `@MappedSuperclas` is missing. Could you please post `DomainObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but I've solved it already. It had to do with an accidental cascading of removal in a many-to-many relation not mentioned here (I didn't mention it because I thought it wasn't related to the problem). Turns out it was removing everything with one single removal because multiple entries were linked with each other through the many-to-many cascading. After removing the cascade all problems were solved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a nesting of hibernate operations caused by an EntityListener.
During the save operation of some entity, an audit interceptor (listener) would be called and would read stuff from the DB, messing up the session.

The solution was to open a new session and transaction for the interceptor.